# Is it possible to open a file from a network path in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to open media files from a network path like this "\\drive\folder\file", is it possible, if yes how? else is there any other alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to have your end user accessing a file on a server path anyway? I think it's highly unlikely that all your end users are going to have the same network setup. Are you trying to write a native type application using flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the path is not a path belonging to the user's computer or their network you shouldn't have a problem. If the path is on the server or a drive networked to the server, then passing it directly as a path to flash isn't going to work because the path is within the server domain and the flash instance is operating within the users domain. You can always convert local paths to relative paths in a server side script or, grab the binary contents of the file and serve then up to flash through a service (if the original target file is not directly accessible to the end-user via a network request).